# Checkbox on form submit: error keeps displaying on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that requires a user to click a checkbox before it can submit. On Submit if the user has not checked the box I display a error message. Currently if I keep clicking the message keeps adding. How do I change this so it only displays once.

```
    onFormSubmit : function(isFormValid, event){
      if ($('#agree_to_terms_join').prop('checked')) {
        $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().removeClass('has-error').find('.error').remove();
      } else {
        $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().addClass('has-error').append(
          '<div class="textbox-alert help-block error"  style="display: block;">' +
            '<div class="type" style="display: block;">Message goes here</div>' +
          '</div>'
        );
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this solution may require extra work and changing some html, but this is the better approach:

- Keep the html block in the form itself
- And toggle the visibility based on the errors using CSS.

**JS**

```
onFormSubmit: function(isFormValid, event) {
    var elem = $('#agree_to_terms_label');
    elem.is(":checked") ? elem.parent().removeClass("error"):elem.parent().addClass("error");
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.has-error .error {
    display: block;
}

.error {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="textbox-alert help-block error">
    <div class="type" style="display: block;">Message goes here</div>
</div>
```

You can keep this HTML in the form itself. Toggling the class will be faster than changing the DOM

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are appending and additional HTML div each time an error occurs. So every error will add another div. Usually people solve this problem by having the error Div in the original markup with a default `hidden` CSS class applied. When the user makes an error the `hidden` class is removed. When the error is fixed the `hidden` class is added back on.

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

It also looks like you're using jQuery, so you can just use the [show() / hide()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand that if you click multiple times, it shows more than one time the same message.

You can check if the element already has class has-error.

Something like this :

```
onFormSubmit : function(isFormValid, event) {
  if ($('#agree_to_terms_join').prop('checked')) {
      $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().removeClass('has-error').find('.error').remove();
  } else {
      if (!$('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().hasClass('has-error')) {
          $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().addClass('has-error').append(
            '<div class="textbox-alert help-block error"  style="display: block;">' +
              '<div class="type" style="display: block;">Message goes here</div>' +
            '</div>'
          );
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `#append` method you could use the [`#html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method like this:

```
    onFormSubmit : function(isFormValid, event){
  if ($('#agree_to_terms_join').prop('checked')) {
    $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().removeClass('has-error').find('.error').remove();
  } else {
    $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().addClass('has-error').html(
      '<div class="textbox-alert help-block error"  style="display: block;">' +
        '<div class="type" style="display: block;">Message goes here</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

I would also suggest you to cache the jquery calls in order to improve the performance, check out [this article](https://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if(!$('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
           alert("You must check the checkbox"); 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if you have already appended the message to the parent of #agree_to_terms_label for appending the error message.

```
if ($('#agree_to_terms_label+div.error').length == 0) {
  $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().addClass('has-error').append(
    '<div class="textbox-alert help-block error"  style="display: block;">' +
    '<div class="type" style="display: block;">Message goes here</div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
}
```

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/he5cx50m/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to check if the the message was already displayed.

`var isErrorMsgDisplayed = false;
onFormSubmit : function(isFormValid, event){
      if ($('#agree_to_terms_join').prop('checked')) {
        $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().removeClass('has-error').find('.error').remove();
    isErrorMsgDisplayed = false;
      } else {
        if(!isErrorMsgDisplayed){
        $('#agree_to_terms_label').parent().addClass('has-error').append(
          '<div class="textbox-alert help-block error"  style="display: block;">' +
            '<div class="type" style="display: block;">Message goes here</div>' +
          '</div>'
        );
        isErrorMsgDisplayed = true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }`